# template call inside ngView not support angular directive stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-view

My question involves how to use `AngularJS directives` in the template called inside `ngView` in an AngularJS application.

**Define :**
The application is single-page, so it loads an index.html that contains a div element(template url) in the DOM with the ng-view attribute.

`Main Page(`**index.html**`) :`

```
<html data-ng-app="App" data-ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <head>
    <title>Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script> 
  </head>
<body>
<!-- primary nav -->
<a href="#/page1">Page 1</a>
<a href="#/page2">Page 2</a>
<a href="#/page3">Page 3</a>

<!-- display the view -->
<div ng-view>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js :**

```
angular.module('App', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($rootScope, appLoading) {
    $rootScope.topScope = $rootScope;
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
      appLoading.loading();
    });
  })

.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/page1', {
      controller : 'Page1Ctrl',
      templateUrl : 'page1.html'
    })
    .when('/page2', {
      controller : 'Page2Ctrl',
      templateUrl : 'page2.html'
    })
    .when('/page3', {
      controller : 'Page3Ctrl',
      templateUrl : 'page3.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
  })
```

**page1.html :**

```
<div class="form">
<form class="login-profile" method="post" action="" name="editfrm">
<input type="text" name="email" value="" id="txtemail" data-ng-model="email" required>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" id="txtpassword" data-ng-model="password" required>
<input type="button" value="Save" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

**Problem :**
Template Url called inside the `ngView` not supported any `AngularJS deirective`.
`data-ng-model="email"` & `data-ng-model="password"` not working when called in the ngView on click the link `<a href="#/page1">Page 1</a>`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @MikkoViitala, Can you please help me in elaborate more your comment.

Comment: Yes, post JS code of your Page1Ctrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing code for your `Page1Ctrl` it's hard to tell but it seems like you are trying to share data between controllers using `$rootScope`, no?

Well, just don't. Use either `$routeParams` or a service for that purpose. For example:

```
// app controller   
.controller('AppCtrl', function(User) {
  User.set({email:'email', password:'password'}); // set user
})

// page 1 controller
.controller('Page1Ctrl', function($scope, User) {
  $scope.user = User.get(); // get user
})

// user service      
.service('User', function() {
  var user = null;
  return {
    get: function() {
      return user;
    },
    set: function(val) {
      user = val;
    }
  };
});
```

and related HTML

```
<input type="text" 
       name="email" 
       data-ng-model="user.email" 
       required>
<input type="password" 
       name="password" 
       data-ng-model="user.password" 
       required>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on `<a href="#/page1">Page 1</a>`, it loads `Page1Ctrl` and `page1.html`. Are you sure you are not able to access `$scope.email` and `$scope.password` in `Page1Ctrl`.

It should be accessible, if not then try to create a model object as follows:

```
$scope.LoginProfile = {
       email: '',
       password: ''
}
```

and use this `LoginProfile` object in your `page1.html` like this `LoginProfile.email` and `LoginProfile.password`.

PS: Try to interpolate on html so you can view values, (e.g. `LoginProfile: {{LoginProfile}}`)

Comment: Thanks for this answer i will try to implement it in this way..Is there any need to call `angularJS.min` script in page1.html ? as it already call in main page(index.html)

Comment: No. On SPA, only the entry point(index.html) contains the library js(angular, bootstrap, etc) and css files. Other htmls are just templates or partials that gets injected into `<ng-view>` using ajax call. So you dont need to include `angular.min.js` (or any other js) in `page1.html`.